# PartialFailureError when inserting data from pubsub to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Im following this guide: [GUIDE](https://medium.com/google-cloud/build-a-weather-station-using-google-cloud-iot-core-and-mongooseos-7a78b69822c5) and i keeping getting an "PartialFailureError: A failure occurred during this request." when im trying to insert data to bigQuery with cloud functions.

I have 2 functions: `insertIntoBigquery()` and `updateCurrentDataFirebase()`. The `updateCurrentDataFirebase()` function works as expected. This means that the reason for error must be by the function `bigquery.dataset('weather_station_iot').table('raw_data').insert(data);`

```
const data = { 
    deviceId: deviceId,
    timestamp: context.timestamp,
    temp: payload.temp,
    humidity: payload.hum
}; 

return Promise.all([
    insertIntoBigquery(data),
    updateCurrentDataFirebase(data)
]);
```

this works

```
function updateCurrentDataFirebase(data) {
    return db.ref(`/devices/${data.deviceId}`).set({
        humidity: data.humidity,
        temp: data.temp,
        lastTimestamp: data.timestamp
    });
}
```

this return the error

```
function insertIntoBigquery(data) {
    return bigquery
    .dataset('weather_station_iot')
    .table('raw_data') 
    .insert(data); 
}
```

Comment: One of the reasons for PartialFailureError is the spelling mistake in the table name, can you check the table and dataset name?

Comment: yes the names are correct.

Comment: Dear people of the future. Since this is one of the top results when searching for this error, if you see this it most likely means that something doesn't match between your schema and your data. Since the OP didn't share their schema I can't say what the problem was there. If the error doesn't give more information it might be worth splitting a bulk insert into multiple single inserts just for testing (though this isn't a problem for the OP).

Comment: i see this error when i added new column to bigquery table, then immediately load the a row with new column into the table.
after a while, the error doesn't occured anymore.
looks like bigquery took some time to update table schema. so the error is probably about the column doesn't exist at the moment in my case.

Answer (score 2):

For whoever seeking for relevant assistant over this issue:

After investing couple of hours in this, I agree that this is indeed a schema misfit issue.

**Problem:** it is pretty hard to understand what went wrong (error message is pretty unclear)

**Solution:**

1. Create a test table with a single field (of type `string`)
2. Use your code to insert data (without any flags or custom configuration)
3. Verify record is properly inserted
4. Extend schema with another field
5. Repeat testing and inspect errors

In my case I use the following code (`Node JS`):

```
  try {
    await cluster.dataset('{DATASET-GOES-HERE}').table('{TABLE}').insert(items)
  } catch (response) {
    console.log(response.errors)
  }
```

Where `items` variable is a simple json. My schema used fields name `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` (for testing purposes), so I've started with a json looks like this

```
{ "a": "test record" }
```

After verifying it works I proceeded to other data types (`b` -> `integer`, `c` -> `timestamp`, etc.) and my payload updated as well

```
{ "a": "test record", "b": 800, "c": 1653825665 }
```

**What I find:**

- The `errors` section inside the response object (when error occurs) is any array of errors with an actual meaningful error description
- When using timestamp - you either need to divide your value by 1000 or simply send ISO string using `new Date().toISOString()` or else you will get an error similar to this - `Timestamp field value is out of range`
- When defining a `record` you MUST switch `mode` to `repeated` or else you probably get `Array specified for non-repeated field` which means you can't populate record with values properly
- It takes a couple of seconds for schema to update so if you get `no such field` error - just wait a bit and give it another try
- I've used the graphical console to create test table as well as updating its schema and delete it in the end - very convenient and straightforward
- The `preview` option to view table data is not refreshing very often - prefer to use a query to inspect your results instead

---

**Here's the schema I tested (in red - the wrong definition of a record)**

[image: table schema]

---

**And this is how I query and verified my results**

[image: table records]

---